# Using Moose in Perl to implement a functor

Tags: perl, functor, moose

I'm working with some code in Perl that wants me to pass a method to it.  But, I'd like to keep some state about what happens in the method.  I know I can use a global variable for this, but I'd prefer something a little cleaner/object oriented.  Is there a way to use Moose to create a functor/function object?

Comment: what do you mean by "pass a method to it"?  I suspect you may just mean a closure and Moose isn't even required to do what you want.  a more concrete example would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need a closure.

```
sub make_closure {
   my ($name) = @_;
   my @greets = ('Good morning', 'Good afternoon', 'Good evening', 'Good night');
   my $next = 0;
   return sub { "$greets[ $next++ % @greets ], $name" };
}

my $joe  = make_closure("Joe");
my $jane = make_closure("Jane");

say $joe->();  # Good morning, Joe
say $joe->();  # Good afternoon, Joe
say $jane->(); # Good morning, Jane
say $jane->(); # Good afternoon, Jane
say $jane->(); # Good evening, Jane
say $joe->();  # Good evening, Joe
```

The other way would be to make an object that [overloads](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?overload) `&{}`.

```
use Moose;

use overload '&{}' => \&call;

has code   => ( is => 'rw' );
has called => ( is => 'rw', default => 0 );

sub call {
   my ($self) = @_;
   $self->called( $self->called() + 1 );
   return $self->code;
}
```

```
my $o = __PACKAGE__->new(code => sub { say "called!" });
$o->();          # called!
$o->();          # called!
say $o->called;  # 2
```